# Releasing artifacts individually within a multi module - aggregator maven project

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Would like to break down the question in two parts

1. Does maven provide anyway to update release version individually for each module under a multi module project.
2. The aggregator pom (root project) has a parent module and other dependent modules, hence want to release the parent module with a version and update that version in the other dependent modules.

Using maven 3.6.2

Have tried release:prepare-with-pom but it uses the root/parent version across all modules.

E.g.

```
   AggregatorPom -> modules -- module1 (independent module, not dependent 
                                        on parent)
                               parent module
                               module2 (dependent on parent module)
                               module3 (dependent on parent module)
```

As per the above example I want to release each individual module with the next release version and when the parent module is released - would want to use the release version of parent in all the dependent modules.

Comment: Sorry, I find it difficult to understand your question. Could you give an example and describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hey @JFabianMeier - have updated the question for better clarity. Do let me know in case it is still not clear what I am trying to achieve and I can try to edit it further or rephrase if possible

Comment: Could you please add a concrete example, with POMs and the expected and actual outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, may be the

https://github.com/danielflower/multi-module-maven-release-plugin

is what you are looking for.

It allows you to release different modules with different versions.

Comment: Thank you @J Fabian Meier - This is a good starting point for me - now the only thing to figure out is - from the above e.g. module 2 and module 3 are dependent on parent module, hence will need to use the parent module released version in them. Do let me know if you have some pointers.